Auto-Stereograms. Find vectors whose elements are limited to the range 0 to 1 and which satisfy the following equations
I figured out what I believe is an entirely new way of generating auto stereograms (3D without glasses). It relies on being able to solve the following equations. Given two sets $l_i$ and $r_i$, each/all of which is limited to the range 0 to m, how can I find vectors whose elements are also limited to the range 0 to 1 which satisfy the following equations? The parameter m is the length of the vectors. The parameter o is a known integer offset $\ge1$ .
$$\vec{_1}\vec{b_1}=mr_1$$
$$\vec{_{1+o}}\vec{b_1}=ml_1$$
$$\vec{_2}\vec{b_2}=mr_2$$
$$\vec{_{2+o}}\vec{b_2}=ml_2$$
$$\vec{_3}\vec{b_3}=mr_3$$
$$\vec{_{3+o}}\vec{b_3}=ml_3$$
etc.
$$\vec{_i} \vec{b_i}=mr_i$$
$$\vec{_{i+o}} \vec{b_{i}}=ml_i$$
$l_i$ and $r_i$ are pixels in the left and right images required to see a stereoscopic image. $f_i$ and $b_i$ are pixels in front and back images that modulate white light to produce the two different images.

I have been using a random hill walk to find near solutions, i.e. to find f and b that minimises the error, (difference between the left sides of the equations and the right sides), but it is very slow and doesn't find an exact solution. I think there must be a more analytic ways of doing it, or at least of giving the random walk some restrictions to help speed up the search.

Composite Left Right Images

Front/Back images

I take it that $f$ and $b$ are the unknowns that you're solving for. If $r_1 = 2n$, then there's no solution, because even if $f_1$ and $b_1$ are all $1$s, their dot product will be only $n$. To make this a valid problem, you'll therefore want to put some restrictions on $\ell$ and $r$. .

To clarify: so $m$ is the length of each of the vectors or the dimension of each of them?

Yes. m is the length of the vectors which is equivalent to the dimension

I have been using a random hill walk to find near solutions, i.e. to find f and b that minimises the error, (difference between the left sides of the equations and the right sides), but it is very slow and doesn't find an exact solution.

I've read this question at least a half dozen times, and I still don't properly understand what you're asking. Is o given? How many vectors f_i and b_i are there? m is the number of elements in each f_i and b_i right? What kind of 'error' are you trying to minimise?

@SimonGoater. o is a known offset. There are as many vectors as pixels in the image being generated. The error should be zero. It is the difference between the desired perceived image (the ls and rs) and the sums of the vector products.

@MichaelMcLaughlin Using difference allows for +ve and -ve errors appear to cancel out. Maybe you should be trying to minimise the square of the difference,

@SimonGoater. That is what I do in my hill walk search, I minimise the sum of the squares of the differences, but maybe it is a good strategy here too. To find a minimum analytically. Thanks.

I assume that $o$ is a nonnegative integer. If $o=0$ then the equations reduce to $\vec{f_i}\vec{b_i}=l_i=r_i$ and can be solved independently of each other. The case $o>0$ essentially can be transformed to $o$ independent cases with the offset $1$, by considering the chains
$$\vec{f_k}\to\vec{b_k}\to\vec{f_{k+o}}\to \vec{b_{k+o}}\to\dots$$
$k\in \{1,\dots,o\}$ separately. So below we suppose that $o=1$.
If I understood the question right, we still need to impose restrictions on $l_i$ and $r_i$ in order to a solution to exists. For instance, if $l_1=m$ then $\vec{f_1}=\vec{b_1}=(1,1,\dots,1)$. Since $\vec{f_2}\vec{b_1}=r_1$, the sum of the entries of $\vec{f_2}$ is $r_1$. Then $r_1\ge \vec{f_2}\vec{b_2}=l_2$.
On the other hand, for $m=2$ we can put $\vec{f_i}=f_i(\cos\alpha_i,\sin\alpha_i)$ and $\vec{b_i}=b_i(\cos\beta_i,\sin\beta_i)$ with $\alpha_i,\beta_i\in \left[0,\frac\pi{2}\right]$ for each $i$.
Then the equations transforms to $f_ib_i\cos(\alpha_i-\beta_i)=l_i$ and $f_{i+o}b_i\cos(\varphi_{i+o}-\beta_i)=r_i$.
Now we shall try to built their solutions consecutively.
A good case is when all $l_i$ and $r_i$ are in the range $\left[\frac 1{\sqrt{2}},1\right]$, because then there exists a solution with all $b_i$ and $r_i$ equal $1$. Indeed, pick any angle $\alpha_1\in \left[0,\frac\pi{2}\right]$ then pick an angle $\beta_1\in \left[0,\frac\pi{2}\right]$ such that $\cos(\alpha_1-\beta_1)=l_1$, then an angle $\alpha_2\in [0,\pi_2]$ such that $\cos(\beta_1-\alpha_2)=r_1$, and so forth.
This idea can be generalized for $m\ge 2$ as follows. Let $p$ and $P$ be the minimum and the maximum, respectively, of all $l_i$ and $r_i$. We can build a solution consecutively provided there exists a subset $S$ of the unit square $Q_m=[0,1]^m$ such that for each vector $\vec{v}\in S$ and each value $x\in [p,P]$ there exists a vector $\vec{u}\in S$ such that $\vec{v}\vec{u}=x$. For instance, in the previous paragraph $p=\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}$, $P=1$, and $S$ is the intersection of $Q_2$ with the circle of radius $R=1$ centered at the origin $(0,0)$. If we allow $R$ to vary from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$ then we can ensure $P$ equal to $R^2$ and $p$ equal to $\frac {R^2}{\sqrt{2}}$ for $R\le 1$ and equal to $\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1+\sqrt{R^2-1}\right)$ for $R\ge 1$.

Looks like a very interesting answer. I am going to enjoy understanding it. Yes, o is a non-negative integer, in fact it must be 1 or more, otherwise the two images have to be the same.

@MichaelMcLaughlin Thank you for your kind words. Unfortunately, the answer is very partial, but I hope it can be helpful to advance the problem understanding.

Yes it doesn't solve it but it gave me good food for thought
